# Navbar is not inline

Tags: html, css

I have got a navbar problem again, because I had to change the code ect due to the navbar code overriding other contents on the page, but anyway The Nvigation text is not inline and I am finding it difficult to get it inline even after over an hor of research i am unable to find the answer..

My HTML Code:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

My CSS Code:

```
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center
}

.navbar a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? If so, what version?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `.navbar a` either inline-block or block. Your padding will not be applied as the `a` is inline by default.

```
.navbar a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you make the following changes.

1. Add the flexbox property to your .navbar class
2. Add align-items property center to your .navbar class - will align all the item menus
3. Get rid of display: inline-block on all your

```css
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
   display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}
 
.navbar a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
 
// .dropdown {
//     display: inline-block;
//     overflow: hidden;
// }
 
.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    //display: inline-block;
}
 
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}
 
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
 
.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
 
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
 
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Done what you told me, but the the text has moved to the left and I want it in the center of the navigation bar

Comment: Flexbox is not necessary to make his intended styling happen.

Comment: add this to .navbar class justify-content: center;

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow Kyle!

The problem resides in not having a `vertical-align` style declaration on your `.dropdown .dropbtn` CSS class declarations. Add it in as shown below:

```
.dropdown, .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; // Add this!
}
```

You'll also need to add a comma between the classes to make sure the styles are applied to both class declarations!

Here is a link to a codepen where you can view the result:
https://codepen.io/mikeabeln_nwea/pen/pxaMKV

Answer (score 0):

I checked out your CSS in pastebin. I added

`.navbar {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}`

and you could also delete the `text-align:center` property